# Eclipse Plugin : create new custom file in wizard

Tags: eclipse-plugin, customization

**While creating an Eclipse custom plugin:**

I have created a custom wizard to get the name of the new custom project to be created.

After creating the project, it need to be able to create a file with a custom extension, something like **`.PROPERTIES`** (the file extension should be a constant one).

The execution design is as follows:

1. **After giving the Project Name after selecting NEW-->General--> Project, a window like the following must appear**

[image]

P.S. I have already tried the code given in the site:
http://blog.cypal-solutions.com/2008/07/how-to-create-new-file-wizard.html
but it was not working.

I request you to help me, seem confused regarding this.

Comment: This question seems quite open ended.  My first thought is that Eclipse already supplies a new file wizard that can be used to create files in any project.  My second  thought was to point you to the faq so that you can better focus your question on the part of this task that you are stuck on.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @twindham : Thanks for the reply!
I did not know about the NEW FILE WIZARD until just now.

I'm sorry, I did not ask the right question--->I have edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

here is an example for what you are looking for http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2008/07/how-to-create-new-file-wizard.html